# STM32 - Why is my function stopped and taken over by another?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I have a main file that's running on a STM32F4 chip with ThreadX running in the background (part of the WICED SDK for those of you who know). In this case I'm not use any of the ThreadX APIs.

My code is set up like this:

```
void func_a(void) {
  ...
  interact_over_spi();
}

void func_b(void) {
  ...
}

int main() {
  func_a();
  func_b();
}
```

In **func_a()**, it's interacting with a serial NOR flash chip over SPI. But every time it executes, it seems like it's terminated early after a second or so. I noticed this because **interact_over_spi()** would be printing out messages to serial console, and then all of a sudden stop and the messages from **func_b()** starts to print.

I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting this. Is there a length limit on how long a function would run? Like I said, I'm using ThreadX by default and not using any thread management functions yet. I also noticed that the problem went away when I put the device under GDB. It seems like having breakpoints in the middle of the **interact_over_spi()** forces it to run till completion. Any ideas why?

Comment: "I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting this." - A debugger would be the natural choice.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: There is no limit to how long a function can run, take a typical `main` from an embedded project, they usually contain a `while(1)` and run forever.

Comment: There is no limit on execution time, but if you have enabled a hardware watchdog and are not servicing it, your processor will be reset.  However in this case it seems that `interact_over_spi()` is simply returning - without seeing that code, it is not possible to tell why.  ThreadX is not the issue here - you have not initialised or started the scheduler (`tx_kernel_enter()`), so it is not running - it is probably not even linked if you are not calling its API.

Comment: _It seems like having breakpoints in the middle of the interact_over_spi() forces it to run till completion._.....It smells like GDB stops other interrupt whe breakpoint is reached, avoiding your problem. Try disabling interrupt at the start of your function and re-enable them at the end.

Comment: Well I am using ST Link V2 and OpenOCD and remote GDB as my debugger. I doubt it's an interrupt issue because func_b() is not an interrupt, never registered as one. And to Colin's point, func_b() indeed has a while (1) loop in it that runs fine/forever. And also I doubt it's a watchdog issue, because a watchdog reset would have restarted the entire main() program instead of going on to func_b(). I'm wondering if this could be a MCU entering sleep mode issue?

Comment: In my experience, weird unexplainable behavior is usually the result of a stack overflow.  Increase the stack size and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Just an update, it indeed seems like it was running out of memory. Or at least the memory allocated for the main thread (6144 available, which is created by the Cypress WICED SDK by default).